# Как лучше хранить данные личных записей пользователей?

Tags: mysql

Есть задача хранить записи пользователей (Заголовок, Текст, дата и так далее). Эти записи будут доступны только самому пользователю (aka личный блокнот).

Я вижу два варианта хранения

1. Каждая запись будет хранится отдельно с столбцами `ID`, `UserID`, `Titile`, `Text` и так далее
2. Хранить записи в виде JSON, в отдельной ячейке записи юзера.

Я считаю, что первый вариант лучше. Может вы знаете ещё способы?

Comment: У каждого пользователя своя учётная запись? или как всегда - одна на всех?

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, если это соц. сеть где есть возможность писать личные записи, то проще использовать 1 вариант, добавив к таблице статус записи, который идентифицирует её, как личную или нет.

Например, добавить атрибут **Private**, в котором будет указываться на тип записи.

После этого просто проверять на тип записи перед выводом.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).